# Does .ajaxStart() only trigger on jQuery initiated Ajax queries or on any Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i go to websites such as 9gag or YouTube, open console(I've included jQuery source in my console) and enter the jQuery command:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  alert('ajax');
});
```

I get nothing, even when i'm sure ajax is getting triggered when 9gag reaches the end of the page and loads new content, or when new comments are loaded on YouTube page ..

Comment: Are you sure that either of those sites uses jQuery and that it can be used as `$` in the console?

Comment: i've included jquery into console

Comment: var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

Comment: I'm not sure that all ajax requests use `.ajaxStart`, just `$.ajax` ones.  So to answer your question, "yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajaxStart` is a type of a [jQuery Ajax Event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/). They are implemented on the `$.ajax` function and are trigged from within there. See the relevant source line on [GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L468).

So, `$.ajaxStart` will be only triggered for events that are fired with the jQuery implementation of `$.ajax` or it's derived implementations like `$.get` etc.